# Example Code for Victory Zoom and Brush Guide

Tags: reactjs, charts, victory-charts

I want to create a chart similar to the example chart in the [Victory Brush and Zoom Guide](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/brush-and-zoom). I just found this library and this example is exactly what I want to do.

I wonder if there is some example code beside the description in the guide available? Does anybody know where I can find it?

I really appreciate any help from you! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code of the [Brush and Zoom Guide](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/brush-and-zoom/) is in the grey box under the example graph.
In my Browser it's just necessary to click in the box and then click outside the box and the code will appear. So all the code is there but maybe it won't show up because of a strange focusing error.